# Проблема с boost::regex_search

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, boost

В приведенном коде в самом внутреннем цикле в блоке `try {} catch{}` проверяются регулярные выражения.

Одно из регулярных выражений - "jquery.*\.js"
оно не срабатывает.

но если закоментировать блок `try catch`
и раскоментировать блок выше который закоментирован `/*...*/`
то регулярное выражение сработает и в webAppFound будет добавлен элемент.

разница в том что в таком случае

```
static const boost::regex e(itrTypeItem->second);
boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> results;
```

вот этот объект и переменная будут объявлены только в одном случае.

```
using namespace std;

class WebappDetector
{
public:
    std::multimap<string, std::multimap<string, std::multimap<string, string>>> appsRegex;

    WebappDetector()
    {
        loadJsonRegex();
    }

    void loadJsonRegex()
    {
        std::stringstream ss = getJson();


        boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
        boost::property_tree::read_json(ss, pt);

        int counter = 0;

        BOOST_FOREACH(boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type &v, pt.get_child("apps"))
        {
            std::multimap<string, std::multimap<string, string>> patternsMap;
            BOOST_FOREACH(boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type &patterns, v.second.get_child(""))
            {
                std::multimap<string, string> regexItems;
                BOOST_FOREACH(boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type &patternsRegex, patterns.second.get_child(""))
                {
                    regexItems.insert(std::make_pair(patternsRegex.first.data(), patternsRegex.second.data()));
                }

                if (patterns.second.empty())
                {
                    regexItems.insert(std::make_pair("", patterns.second.data()));
                }


                patternsMap.insert(std::make_pair(patterns.first.data(), regexItems));
            }

            appsRegex.insert(std::make_pair(v.first.data(), patternsMap));
        }
    }

    vector<string> testRegex()
    {
        vector<string> webAppFound;

        std::stringstream htmlExample = getHtmlExample();
        string htmlExampleStr = htmlExample.str();

        int counter = 0;

        for (auto itr = appsRegex.begin(); itr != appsRegex.end(); ++itr)
        {
            std::multimap<string, std::multimap<string, string>> regexTypes = itr->second;

            for (auto itrType = regexTypes.begin(); itrType != regexTypes.end(); ++itrType)
            {
                if (/*itrType->first == "html" || */itrType->first == "script" /* || itrType->first == "headers" || itrType->first == "script" || itrType->first == "meta" || itrType->first == "website"*/) {

                    std::multimap<string, string> regexItem = itrType->second;

                    for (auto itrTypeItem = regexItem.begin(); itrTypeItem != regexItem.end(); ++itrTypeItem)
                    {
                        //cout << itrType->first << "; regex: " << itrTypeItem->second << endl;

                        /*if (!itrTypeItem->second.compare("jquery.*\\.js")) {
                            cout << "JQuery pattern found " << itrTypeItem->second << endl;

                            static const boost::regex e(itrTypeItem->second);
                            boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> results;
                            if (boost::regex_search(htmlExampleStr, results, e)) {
                                webAppFound.push_back(itr->first);
                            }

                            return webAppFound;
                        }*/

                        //cout << itrTypeItem->second << endl;
                        //counter++;

                        try
                        {
                            static const boost::regex e(itrTypeItem->second);
                            boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> results;
                            if (boost::regex_search(htmlExampleStr, results, e)) {
                                webAppFound.push_back(itr->first);
                            }

                            counter++;
                        }
                        catch (boost::regex_error& e)
                        { 
                            //std::cout << itrTypeItem->second << std::endl;
                            cout << itrTypeItem->second << " is not a valid regular expression: \"" << e.what() << "\"" << endl;
                            //continue;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        cout << "Iterations regex " << counter << endl;

        return webAppFound;
    }
};
```

Comment: На всякий пожарный, убедитесь наверняка что вызывается нужная версия regex_search

Answer (score 1):

Подозреваю, что не работает из-за того что вы объект `e` объявили статическим:

```
static const boost::regex e(itrTypeItem->second);
```

В верхнем примере вы его инициализируете строкой `"("jquery.*\\.js"))"`, а в нижнем неизвестно чем, но видимо что другим неподходящим выражением.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте убрать модификатор static из объявления объекта e, скорее всего, он инициализируется один раз и не тем регулярным выражением, которое вы ожидаете. В закоментированном блоке же все работает потому, что объект e, используемый в этом блоке, находится в другой области видимости и инициализируется только нужным Вам регулярным выражением.